# Specific Part of Post for Specific User in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post

I am developing a membership based website in wordpress where I installed S2Member plugin and I show a user a welcome page with some quick links. I am now stuck at the point where I want to show specific links for specific usernames. I installed a plugin named peter's login redirect that shows a specific login page to the user but it didn;t work for me as I am already using a S2 Member plugin.

Is there any other way to show a specific link/button/post-part for the specific user?

Comment: Please, define "part of post". Is it inside the template? Inside the normal content? A widget? Something else?

Comment: basically, it's a page named welcome that appears when you logged in the website. I want to show specific content on that page for specific user. my website is: jetdigitzing.com. you can make over there a test account as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is using a [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), you can detect the user name, user role or something else contained in the WP_User object:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SO) Welcome Shortcode
 */

add_shortcode( 'welcome', 'welcome_so_23702194' );

function welcome_so_23702194( $atts, $content = null ) 
{
    $user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );

    if( !$user ) // Normal visitor, nor logged in
        return '';

    # Use the following to inspect the object, and do at the end --> return $debug;
    // $debug = '<pre>' . print_r( $user, true ) . '</pre>';

    if( 'brasofilo' == $user->data->user_login )
        $output = "Hello, brasofilo!";
    elseif( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) )
        $output = "Hello, admininstrator user";
    else
        $output = '';
    return $output;
}
```

Then, in your Welcome page add the shortcode in the middle of the content `[welcome]`.

Comment: This one is working but I am not going to use this website but my client so he is not too code savvy to replace the codes each time. Your idea is best but unfortunately I am searching to make a plugin to resolve this.

Comment: Maybe the plugin Advanced Custom Fields can help. You make a custom meta box that shows only when editing the Welcome page, the client adds information and the shortcode uses this info to render.